# Find-item Greaterthan not recognized by SPE 3.0

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm working on a PSE script that will work on different sitecore environment with different sitecore versions. This script basically get the list of items that is recently updated between to given dates.

```
$fromdate = New-Object DateTime 2020, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, ([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
$todate = New-Object DateTime 2020, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, ([DateTimeKind]::Utc)

$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "GreaterThan"; Field = "__smallupdateddate"; Value = $fromdate}
    @{Filter = "LessThan"; Field = "__smallupdateddate"; Value = $todate} 
)
#return list code goes here
```

However in one of the environments with SPE 3.0 installed that script is not working. anyone could help me how to do this that is compatible with lower versions of SPE? This is the error I am getting:

> Find-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'Criteria'. Cannot create object of
> type "Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.Data.Search.SearchCriteria".
> Cannot convert value "GreaterThan" to type
> "Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.Data.Search.FilterType". Error:
> "Unable to match the identifier name GreaterThan to a valid enumerator
> name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
> None, Equals, StartsWith, Contains, ContainsAll, ContainsAny,
> EndsWith, DescendantOf, Fuzzy, InclusiveRange, ExclusiveRange,
> MatchesRegex, MatchesWildcard"

Thanks,
Borj

Comment: SPE 3.0!? It's January 2021 and SPE 6.2 is released.

Comment: There are old websites that is still using it.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Powershell Extensions 3.0 contains only next filter types:

```
None,
Equals,
StartsWith,
Contains,
EndsWith
```

Please upgrade PowerShell to the latest version. You will get bigger list of filters:

```
None,
Equals,
StartsWith,
Contains,
ContainsAll,
ContainsAny,
EndsWith,
DescendantOf,
Fuzzy,
InclusiveRange,
ExclusiveRange,
MatchesRegex,
MatchesWildcard,
GreaterThan,
LessThan
```

And as there is `GreaterThan` and `LessThan` - your code will start to work